# Если equals для String, тогда почему == для null?

Tags: java

Известно, что ссылочные типы необходимо сравнивать с помощью equals.
Есть нюансы, что для Integer в диапазоне от -128 до 127 сравнение происходит с помощью == и это отдельная история.
Вопрос, почему

```
String line;
while(!(line = br.readLine()).equals("ESC")){}
```

и в тоже время

```
String line;
while((line = br.readLine()) != null){}
```

Почему с null сравниваем с помощью ==?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/142968/%D0%97%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-null-%D0%B2-java

Comment: "Есть нюансы, что для Integer в диапазоне от -128 до 127 сравнение происходит с помощью == и это отдельная история." - это некорректное утверждение. Например, new Integer(12) == new Integer(12) будет false

Comment: @fromSPb
`Integer a = 12;
        Integer b = 12;
        Integer c = new Integer(12);
        Integer d = new Integer(12);
        Integer e = 200;
        Integer f = 200;
        System.out.println(a == b);//true
        System.out.println(c == d);//false
        System.out.println(e == f);//false`
Вот так, да? Почему так?

Comment: @GrossmasteR при явном создании через конструктор числа из кэша не берутся, поэтому при Integer а = 12 и Integer b = new Integer(12) сравнение a==b вернёт false, т.к. переменные a и b указывают на разные объекты - объект, на который указывает а, находится в кэше, а тот, на который указывает b - нет

Answer (score 1):

Java берет начало из C++, тот -- из C. В Java `null` остался ссылкой на пустое значение.

В C же по стандарту любые два объекта, указывающие на `null`, равны.

Источник: [ISO/IEC 9899](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf)
параграф 6.3.2.3, пункт 4.

```
... Any two null pointers shall compare equal.
```

Кроме того, у `null` нет метода (функции) [`equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29), т.е. код ниже приведет к исключению:

```java
((String)null).equals(null)
```

Почему у `null` нет функций? Ссылка опять к языку C.

Comment: не "на пустое значение", а "на отсутствие значения" )

Comment: @AndrewBystrov думаю, это субъективно. В свою пользу могу привести 2 аргумента: а) близость перевода б) различие компилятора при работе с неинициализированными переменными и с `null`